# $K=0$ at each point of a line on a surface that locally lies on one side of the tangent plane

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose a surface $S$ contains a parametrized line $\alpha(s)$. At each point $p\in \alpha(s)$, the surface $S$ near $p$ lies on one side of the tangent plane of $S$ at $p$. Show that $K=0$ at $p$.

I honestly do not know where to begin with this problem. I've read in do Carmo that if a surface $S$ lies on one side of $T_pS$, then $K>0$, but clearly that isn't the case here for some reason, so I'm confused. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: We have defined the Gaussian curvature to be the determinant of the differential of the Gauss map: $K=det[dN_p]$.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the statement is that *if* $K>0$ at every point, then the surface lies on one side of each tangent plane.

A line contained in a surface is, in particular, an asymptotic curve and so at points $p$ of the line we have $K(p)\le 0$. However, if we had $K(p)<0$, the principal curvatures would have opposite signs and you can deduce from this that a neighborhood of the surface around $p$ lies on *both* sides of the tangent plane.